# Windows API in outlook to cover send button

Tags: c#, vba, winapi, outlook-addin

I've been tasked with removing the send button in outlook, not just from the ribbon but from the message form. I've tried making some custom forms but they always seem to be lacking. We also have a custom button solution using them Item_send event, so tying into that event was causing issues.

I have been toying around with a different idea, to use the windows API to add a button over the Default send button.

I've done some research on this and have only found 1 suggestion to this being possible but the post didn't include too much information. My question is threefold, is it even possible? Is it a good idea? If so, where do I start?

p.s. Normally I'm a mobile engineer so I feel like a fish out of water when even googling stuff about the windows API but i'm confident I can pick it up with time.

Comment: *"Is it a good idea?"* - Removing the *Send* button from a mail client? No. Doesn't sound like a totally awesome idea to me.

Comment: What on earth is the rationale for that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had included it in the original post. We have a "secure send" developed by a 3rd party that ties into the item_send event. We need to get rid of the default send button because there is no way our users will be able to break the habit of using the default button.

Answer (score 0):

If you need control over the sending process, the accepted and supported mechanism is to hook into the ItemSend event and cancel/approve as required according to your business logic.  Otherwise, removing functionality from Outlook is a bad design decision.

Comment: We're using a 3rd party secure send button called Zix Select. If I mess with the Item_send function too much it achieves our result of disabling the button.. but the secure button stops working. Their dev team isn't very keen on helping us and has given me the cold shoulder a few times. I don't make the business decision, I'm just the code monkey.